# Help With Joomla PHP Upgrade

Tags: joomla-3.x, php7

I need a little bit of guidance when it comes to upgrading PHP on a Joomla! site
The server is running RHEL 8.7 and I have already updated Lampp on my webserver to xampp-linux-x64-7.4.30-1. (this version of lampp contains PHP 7.4.30 & Apache 2.4.54)

The Steps on the Joomla site (in the link below) do not go into depth when it comes to updating php. They direct you to another article about how to setup a lampp server.
https://magazine.joomla.org/all-issues/september-2020/how-do-i-update-my-php-version

The lampp I installed on my web server contains PHP 7.4.3 . I am not clear on how to get that to reflect in Joomla's system information. That is currently displaying version 7.3.17

is it as simple as adding an AddHandler to the htaccess file?

AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74___lsphp .php .php7 .phtml

Here are the relevant specs on my Joomla! site
Joomla Specs
PHP Version:    7.3.17
Web Server: Apache/2.4.54 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1q mod_perl/2.0.12 Perl/v5.34.1
WebServer to PHP Interface: apache2handler
Joomla! Version:    Joomla! 3.9.26 Stable [ Amani ] 13-April-2021 15:00 GMT
Joomla! Platform Version:   Joomla Platform 13.1.0 Stable [ Curiosity ] 24-Apr-2013 00:00 GMT